# How to correctly convert all datetime columns of a dataframe into iso format

Tags: python, json, pandas, datetime

A dataframe with a number of datetime columns aggregated from different sources has inconsistent format.
How to correctly convert all datetime columns into iso format?

Currently, my best solution is to convert the dataframe into json with `date_format='iso'`:

```
json_string = my_dataframe.to_json(orient='records', date_format='iso')
```

and convert it back into dataframe:

```
my_dataframe = pd.read_json(json_string , orient='records')
```

but the solution seems to me more hack rather a proper solution.
How can I convert in more professional way *without using json*?

Comment: Are ALL columns datetimes?

Comment: did you parse all your datetime columns [`to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)? if so, outputting them in ISO format is just a matter of [`strftime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html)...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pandas.to_datetime()` on a column of your dataframe which returns a Datetime Index. [You can specify](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas.to_datetime) how to parse the data of a particular column or have it infer the data format depending on the parameters you choose.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

my_dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'date': '01/03/12'}, index = [0])

my_dataframe['date'] = pd.to_datetime(my_dataframe['date'], dayfirst = True)

print(my_dataframe)
```

Output:

```
        date
0 2012-03-01
```

Python formatting codes can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)